# Change CSS on AJAX request in Wicket

Tags: ajax, wicket, wicket-7

I have a component `A` that should dynamically change the font size of some of it's contents. I currently use CSS variables to do that and the component will contribute some CSS String containing these CSS variables:

```
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
  String fontCss = // dynamically fetch CSS cariables
  response.render(CssHeaderItem.forCSS(fontCss, "font-css"));
}
```

On the same page I have the possibility to change these font sizes using an AJAX update within another component `B`. This will add the component `A` to the `AjaxRequestTarget`, which will cause the `renderHead` method to be executed with updated values for the font CSS variables.

However, I don't see an updated font size in my browser as the old CSS variables still seem to be present. How can I enforce the new CSS to overwrite the old one?

So far I found 2 solutions, that seem like dirty workarounds to me:

1. Add the whole page to the `AjaxRequestTarget`, so the whole page will be refreshed.
2. Add JavaScript to the AJAX update to remove the old styling with:

```
var allStyles = document.getElementsByTagName("style");
for (var style of allStyles) {
  if (style.getAttribute("id").includes("font-css")) {
    style.remove();
  }
}
```

Is there a cleaner solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the problem with workaround 2.

```
response.render(CssHeaderItem.forCSS(fontCss, "font-css"));
```

adds `<style id="font-css"> ... </style>` to the page. Later when the Ajax response contributes the new content the JavaScript logic finds that there is an HTML element with id `font-css` and assumes that there is nothing to do.

A simple solution is to use dynamic id, e.g. by using UUID in `#renderHead()`.
Another solution is to make this `<style>` a proper Wicket Component, a Label, that could be added to the AjaxRequestTarget with an updated Model when needed.

Comment: But using a UUID approach would mean that I still need to remove the old styling with JavaScript, right?

Comment: I didn't understand your second solution at first, but now that I do, this is actually working great. Thanks! (can not upvote due to low reputation)