# Change CSS on AJAX request in Wicket throws exception in dev mode

Tags: wicket, wicket-7, wicket-8

This is a follow-up of [Change CSS on AJAX request in Wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74149837/change-css-on-ajax-request-in-wicket).

I implemented the possibility to change CSS on an AJAX request by making the `<style>` a proper Wicket component. This is used inside my container component (`FontContainerComponent`) as follows:

```
<wicket:head>
  <style wicket:id="css"></style>
</wicket:head>
```

The model of this CSS label (read: the content of my CSS) is added like this:

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeRender() {
  String fontCss = someProvider.getFontCss();
  addOrReplace(new Label("css", fontCss));
  super.onBeforeRender();
}
```

This is added to the Ajax update inside another component's `onClick` method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
  // Irrelevant code left out here...
  target.add(getFontContainer());
}
```

This worked fine in Wicket 7. I've now upgraded my code to Wicket 9 and now an exception is being thrown when my container component is added to an `AjaxRequestTarget`. It still works fine when the page is initially rendered. The exception only appears in development mode also appeared in Wicket 8.

The exception comes from `Page::checkRendering`, which thinks that the style label (id = `css`) is not added to the response:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: The component(s) below failed to render. Possible reasons could be that:
    1) you have added a component in code but forgot to reference it in the markup (thus the component will never be rendered),
    2) if your components were added in a parent container then make sure the markup for the child container includes them in <wicket:extend>.

1. [Component id = css, page = com.example.component.page.MyPage, path = fontContainerComponent:css, type = org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label, isVisible = true, isVersioned = true]
```

So, my questions are:

1. What did change from Wicket 7 to Wicket 8, that causes the exception to happen in this scenario?
2. What can I do to fix it?

For 2: Obviously, I could turn off the check (`application.getDebugSettings().setComponentUseCheck(false)`) or use the different approach from the original question (render the CSS not as a label, but using `renderHead` and then use JavaScript code to remove previously added CSS in each AJAX update), but I'm searching for a solution using my current approach (if possible).

Comment: Please paste the error! And also show the Ajax `onXyz()` method.

Comment: I edited the question to include these details

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the usage of `<wicket:head>`. It does its magic (logic) to move the inner HTML to the `<head>` of the page and somehow breaks the Wicket Component tree.

IMO it would be better to re-work your code to use header contribution:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
  super.renderHead(response);
  response.render(CssHeaderItem.forCSS("...", "my-generated-styles"));
}
```

`my-generated-styles` will be used as an element id for the `<style>` element, so Ajax repaints will replace its body.

Comment: As already stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74150133/19615489 this will not update the CSS after the AJAX request

Comment: Right! Indeed it ignores it - https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/16f99bb57b972ad1b96080e815e0f10f4a3586b5/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/ajax/res/js/wicket-ajax-jquery.js#L1858-L1860 ! IMO it should replace it but I don't remember why it behaves this way ...